# Windows Speech Recognition - Using native commands/dialogs in API

Tags: c#, .net, windows, speech-recognition

I have just started using the Windows Speech Recognition (in Windows 8.1) and the System.Speech API (in C#) which seems to tie into it's underlying engine.

However, the API doesn't seem to have access to the semantic commands and dialogs such as "**Correct [word]**" or "**Correct that**" or "**Spell [word]**" which pull up the Alternates Dialog and Spelling Dialog (which are attractive, easy to use screens that add a lot of power/value)

Is there any way to either get access to these commands/dialogs in the API OR to tie my application into the external Windows Speech Recognition application to support these advanced functions?